# $2$-edge-connected graph has perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

My question was to prove using Tutte theorem that $3$-regular  graphs and $2$-edge-connected graphs have perfect matching.

For the $3$-regular-matching, i found the solution by myself, using Tutte's thorem 
$q(G-S)$ $\leq$ $|$S$|$, for any $S$ in $V$. ( I took a odd component, and made the sum of vertex)

But for the $2$-edge-connected graphs i can't find the connection between the Tutte relation?

Any hints/ideas for the $2$-edge-connected part?

Comment: But it's false that any $2$-edge-connected graph has a perfect matching, e.g., consider any odd cycle.

Comment: I put the question ambigue a bit, maybe. I don't need to prove for any, just that "$a$" 2-edge-connected graph has a perfect matching.

Comment: Ok so take any even cycle.

Comment: I think maybe what you are being asked is to prove that any graph that is both $3$-regular **and** $2$-edge-connected has a perfect matching. (Actually it's not true that any $3$-regular graph has a perfect matching).

Comment: Yes, i think that it its. Now i realise, the connection between 3-regular and 2-edge-connected. Any example of graph, of how to use tutte theorem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph#/media/File:2-edge-connected.jpg, I think that is a graph that is both 2-edge-connected and 3-regular.. Am i right?

Comment: No, that one is not $3$-regular. But for your question, take an $S$ and consider the sum of the degrees of the vertices in $S$. Note that some edges are counted twice, but some just once...

Comment: Ok, i got the idea with sum of degrees, but i still have to use a example. I realised why last example is wrong, i think this is ok https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph#/media/File:3-regular_graph.svg ? beucase if i remove any 1 edge the graph remains connected

Comment: Yes indeed that is an example of a $3$-regular and $2$-edge connected graph.

Comment: But why you siad some edges will be counted twice, and some just once? And as S, i take a odd component?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a 3-regular 2-connected graph. Take any $S\subseteq V(G)$. We aim to show that $q(G-S)\leq |S|$. Here, $q(G-S)$ is the number of odd components of $G-S$. Tutte then gives the required 1-factor. Let $C$ be an odd component of $G-S$. Consider
$$\sum_{v\in V(C)}deg(v)=3|C|.$$
This sum is clearly odd, since $|C|$ is odd. Any edge with both endpoints in $C$ contributes 2 to the sum, whereas any edge with only one endpoint in $C$ contributes 1. As such, edges totally contained in $C$ must contribute only an even part of the sum. Furthermore, any edge with only one endpoint in $C$ must have its other endpoint in $S$, since $C$ is disconnected from the rest of $G$ when $S$ is removed. This fact combined with the fact that the edges contained totally in $C$ contribute only an even portion of the sum gives us that there must be an odd number of edges from $C$ to $S$.

Since $G$ is 2-connected, there cannot be only one edge, so each $C$ must have at least 3 edges to $S$. The total number of edges with an endpoint in $S$ can be at most $3|S|$ since $G$ is 3-regular. As such, 
$$3q(G-S)\leq 3|S|$$
which gives
$$q(G-S)\leq |S|$$
Tutte's theorem gives that $G$ must have a 1 factor.